# django post method to get all value with same name

Tags: html, django

Hi i am trying to build a application using Django. 
I have a form under which i let the use to enter n number of input as they wish. but i am not able to retrieve the data as expected when the submit.

Here is my view

```
def sample(request):
 if request.method == 'POST'
  form_value = request.POST.copy()
  print form_value #This print statement print me <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'gAxkEq1bVk5hQicPGmFo4DTIOxomOUdtaOiimW5Bel1kvFaYyECp5JzPqk4yzJe8'], u'userinput': [u'asddsaf', u'asfsadf', u'asfsdf', u'asfdsaf', u'asfasdf']}>
  print form_value['userinput'] # but this print statment print me only the last value asdfsaf
```

my HTML

```
<form action='.' method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type='text' name='userinput'>
<input type='text' name='userinput'>
<input type='text' name='userinput'>
<input type='text' name='userinput'>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can i get the list/array of input with the name 'userinput'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
form_value.getlist('userinput')
```